# mod_rewrite redirect if file not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, front-controller

I've got a website that use a front controller that redirect traffic to certain files so I can employ SEO friendly URLs however there are some static pages on the site which I don't want traffic directed away from:

I currently have the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exmple.com/$1 [L,R=301]
ErrorDocument  404  /controller.php
```

which seems to work fine:

- All traffic is diverted to `www.example.com`;
- And any web page that isn't found is directed to `controller.php` to handle;
- Anything that actually exists such as `www.example.com/about_us.php` still works;

The problems is that it still reports a 404 error even though the page is still sent and displayed correctly - it doesn't look any different to the end user but its messing up my SEO with Google as the Google bot sees the 404 and assumes there's nothing else there.

Is there any way I can simply redirect all traffic apart from a list of certain pages or is there a more elegant solution?

Any help, thoughts, comments, etc. would be most welcome

Comment: Using what you have got right now -- have you tried sending 200 response code when you successfully route request using `header()` PHP function?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument  404  /controller.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

You should route through index.php... otherwise line below should work instead of upper one.

```
RewriteRule .* $0 [PT]
```

Comment: Considering that OP is already using `/controller.php` to handle all requests to non-existing resources, there is not need for extra `index.php` -- the last line can be easily replaced by this: `RewriteRule .* controller.php [L]`